# Trying to make a cookie clicker style game with Tkinter but Label won't change number

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

This is my code for a simple Tkinter project:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

global cookie_count
cookie_count = "0"
cookies = Label(root, text=cookie_count)
cookies.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

def addCookie(multiplier):
    global cookie_count
    before = cookie_count
    after = int(before) + (1 * multiplier)
    cookie_count = after
    root.update()

add = Button(root, text="Click me!", command=lambda: addCookie(1))
add.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I make it so that the `cookies` label's value changes when I click the button?

Comment: Why would you expect the number on the Label to change?  You haven't written any code to do that, you're only changing variables.

Comment: @martineau what is the basis for tagging this as 2.x?

Comment: @Karl: The `from Tkinter import *`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a tkinter [`IntVar`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) and set the [`textvariable=`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/label.html) option of the `Label` to it, all your `Button` callback function has to do is update the `Intvar`'s value (and the `Label` will update automatically):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ModuleNotFoundError:  # Python 2.x
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cookie_count = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)

cookies = tk.Label(root, textvariable=cookie_count)
cookies.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

def add_cookie(multiplier):
    cookie_count.set(cookie_count.get() + multiplier)

add = tk.Button(root, text="Click me!", command=lambda: add_cookie(1))
add.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I apologized. This code is written in Python 3.x, not Python 2.

I added the import namespace `partial`. Then I added a parameter in the function. Then, in the command button keyword, I added +1. Added `textvariable` in `Label`.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


root = Tk()

variable = IntVar()
cookies = Label(root, textvariable=variable)
cookies.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)


def increment_counter(var: int, amount: int) -> int:
   result=var.get()
   result += amount  
   var.set(result)

add = Button(root, text="Click me!", command=partial(increment_counter, variable, +1))
add.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Aside from the capitalization of the module name, everything else should work the same between 2.x and 3.x here.

Comment: @Karl: Won't work the same in Python 2.x because of the type hints (first introduced into Python in version 3.5). Seems to works OK if they are removed the capitalization of the module name is fixed — although PEP 8 recommends avoiding wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`).

Comment: Totally overlooked those, somehow.